# Visualforce with AJAX toolkit Migration to Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have a Visualforce page exposed as a Tab with heavy javascript and it uses AJAX toolkit. We are in the process migrating to Lighting Experience and this page seems working fine at high level in Lightning and it even uses GETSESSIONID for the AJAX calls.

Have you noticed any issues with similar pages in Lightning? Is this a good candidate to develop completely using Lighting Components but I don't see a reason if it is working fine.

Please let me know your insights.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to rush out immediately, but I'd still recommend converting the page when you get a moment. The AJAX Toolkit burns through API calls/day limits, and Visualforce simply doesn't "look" like Lightning, which provides a less-than-ideal user experience. Other than that, Visualforce will continue to run for the foreseeable future, and the AJAX Toolkit is likely to be around for many years as well, at least until Salesforce can move the majority of customers to a pure Lightning experience, which is still years out.